# Why are we reassigning self.prog_name in the ManagementUtility class?

Tags: django, python-class, manage.py

This is the code snippet in the django that I'm tryin to parse.
[image: https://github.com/django/django/blob/36cd4259438f98e74e472e232307a1909f164e56/django/core/management/init.py]